# How do I better improve the performance of my search function in my Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, search, product-list

How do I better improve the performance of **my search function** in my Magento 2 website.

Every time i try searching a key word, such as `Mi 8`, it doesn't show results with the searched keyword in the **title**. Results such as `Mi 8 pro` & `Mi 8 4+64GB` should show up, but either no results shown or unrelated product listings were shown.

How do i get the search function to display related results for the users when they are searching, to show any listings that have the searched keyword.
 *(Showing all the listings with the word 'Mi' when i search it)*

Comment: have you tried elastic search with you instance ? if you are on 2.3 it is supported with community edition by default

Comment: Elastic Search and the Amasty elastic search module for Magento work great together.  It is what we use.